What skateboarding combat games are at 14:08 of "The Kart Racer Golden Age"?
At 14:08 of Leon Massey's video "The Kart Racer Golden Age", three games are briefly shown as examples of games with combat mechanics that are inspired by Tony Hawk's Pro Skater. The games shown are a skateboarding game with a winged character, a rollerblading game with guns in a desert, and a biking game in a warehouse. I recognize the second game as Rollerdrome, but what are the first and third games?




The first game looks like Helskate.  Images on the Steam page match the UI.
The other game is Motordoom (Motördoom seems to be the actual name but Steam lists it without the "ö").
